# Return value from Parallel.Invoke c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have 4 methods which I uses for Excel generation, each method returns 10000 records from database and push into one excel with different sheets. Each method returns List.

```
CAMSFormat CAMS = new CAMSFormat();

CAMS.CAMSTrailPSI = bl.CAMSTrailPSIoutput(FromDate, ToDate, MemoType);
CAMS.CAMSUpfrontPSI = bl.CAMSUpfrontPSIoutput(FromDate, ToDate, MemoType);
CAMS.CAMSTrailSIPSTP = bl.CAMSTrailSIPSTPoutput(FromDate, ToDate, MemoType);
CAMS.CAMSUpfrontSIPSTP = bl.CAMSUpfrontSIPSTPoutput(FromDate, ToDate, MemoType);
```

And the problem is it is taking more than 2 minutes to return the data.

Now I was thinking make it as concurrent call to database and I forced myself to use Parallel.Invoke .

```
Parallel.Invoke(
    () => bl.CAMSTrailPSIoutput(FromDate, ToDate, MemoType),
    () => bl.CAMSTrailSIPSTPoutput(FromDate, ToDate, MemoType),
    () =>  bl.CAMSUpfrontPSIoutput(FromDate, ToDate, MemoType),
    () => bl.CAMSUpfrontSIPSTPoutput(FromDate, ToDate, MemoType));
```

How do I return values from Parallel.Invoke ? And How  do I assign each List to the main class?

I have changed the above code as below. Declared local lists, List separately and finally attaching to the main class however still I am getting the error. If I don't use Parallel.Invoke, these methods works perfectly fine.

```
List<CAMSTrailPSI> result1 = new List<CAMSTrailPSI>();
List<CAMSUpfrontPSI> result2 = new List<CAMSUpfrontPSI>();

Parallel.Invoke(
    () => {
        result1 = bl.CAMSTrailPSIoutput(FromDate, ToDate, MemoType);
    },
    () => {
        result2 = bl.CAMSUpfrontPSIoutput(FromDate, ToDate, MemoType);
    });
CAMS.CAMSTrailPSI = result1;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a tour at https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Do you _specifically_ want to use `Parallel.Invoke`?

Comment: CAMSFormat is normal class with List of another classes          
   public class CAMSFormat
    {
        public List<CAMSTrailPSI> CAMSTrailPSI { get; set; } }

Comment: We can't see the Excel here but that certainly won't thread-safe. Not so sure about your Db work either.

Comment: Can you be specific about what error do you get?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the calls on the `bl` class are thread-safe then this kind of pattern probably would work best for you:

```
var t_CAMSTrailPSI = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => bl.CAMSTrailPSIoutput(FromDate, ToDate, MemoType));
var t_CAMSUpfrontPSI = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => bl.CAMSUpfrontPSIoutput(FromDate, ToDate, MemoType));
var t_CAMSTrailSIPSTP = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => bl.CAMSTrailSIPSTPoutput(FromDate, ToDate, MemoType));
var t_CAMSUpfrontSIPSTP = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => bl.CAMSUpfrontSIPSTPoutput(FromDate, ToDate, MemoType));

Task.WaitAll(t_CAMSTrailPSI, t_CAMSUpfrontPSI, t_CAMSTrailSIPSTP, t_CAMSUpfrontSIPSTP);

CAMSFormat CAMS = new CAMSFormat();

CAMS.CAMSTrailPSI = t_CAMSTrailPSI.Result;
CAMS.CAMSUpfrontPSI = t_CAMSUpfrontPSI.Result;
CAMS.CAMSTrailSIPSTP = t_CAMSTrailSIPSTP.Result;
CAMS.CAMSUpfrontSIPSTP = t_CAMSUpfrontSIPSTP.Result;
```

The `Task.WaitAll` isn't strictly necessary, but it helps to clarify your intent with the code.

Comment: Just want to emphasize it one more time that `Task.WaitAll` or `Task.WhenAll` not always needed but people try to use them anyway.

Comment: @it3xl - This seems to be your first comment. Why "one more time"? Also, what do you mean by "not always needed but people try to use them anyway"?